# Smoothing of a tree of rational curves with free components in Fano

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one. Let $K$ be a minimal rational component of Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$. Let $d$ be the minimal degree.  Consider a tree $C= C_1 \cup C_2 \cup ...\cup C_m$ with $m$ components, where $C_i \in K, i= 1, 2, ..., m$ and each $C_i$ is free, such that $C_1$ passes through a fixed point $x \in X$. Then it is known that there is a smoothing of $C$ with a general member being free.  Consider all the trees with $x \in C_1$ of length $m$. Then the dimension of such trees is $(d-2)m+(m-1)$.

Question: (1) If none of the components are very free, can a smoothing be very free ?

(2) In this process shall we get a subvariety of dimension $(d-2)m$ of the free curves through $x$ which are not very free ?

Comment: The dimension is not $(d-2)m$, it is $(d-2)m + (m-1)$ because there are $m-1$ nodes that give "additional moduli".

Comment: Yes. Sorry I missed that count.  Is (2) correct ?

Comment: The answer to Question (1) is "yes."  Until the dimension estimate is corrected, I am not quite sure what Question (2) is asking.

Comment: In question (2), I want to know whether the component containing the smoothings of such trees contains a subvariety of dimension $(d-2)m +(m-1)$ which are free but not free.

Comment: Sorry, a typo in the previous comment. It should be free but not very free.

Comment: The locus parameterizing curves that are not very free is determinantal with “expected codimension” equal to $md-n$.

Comment: So the “expected dimension” of the locus of smoothings that are not very free is $n-2$.